# Custom skybox shader for tiled skybox

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am new to writing shaders. I want to use a texture for 6-sided skybox in unity and I want that texture to be repeated several times also called tiling.

But the default 6-sided skybox shader in unity doesn't have tiling option. Can anyone write a custom shader for 6-sided skybox in unity which has option to tile textures? I also want an option to apply a color tint on the texture if possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tiling can be achieved by multiplying texcoord by the number of tiles you want. Or in Surface shader it's uv_YourTex (likely MainTex) instead of texcoord. Writing from a phone so can't post an example, but it's really just one multiplication.

I don't know your specific scenario, but I needed to get more detailed sky with not very detailed texture and instead of UV I used view direction to sample a texture. It made it look like clouds in the distance are further away + clouds can move as you move . It's in this  [asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/shaders/toon-shaded-water-93746). 
View direction sampling will not help if you are trying to make space though, which seams to be the case.

Also IMHO tiling on the skybox might be too visible.